# Selecting strings and using in logical expressions to create new variable - R

Tags: r, string

I have a categorical variable indicating location of flu clinics as well as an "other" category. Participants who select the "other" category give open-ended responses for their location. In most cases, these open-ended responses fit with one of the existing categories (for example, one category is "public health clinic", but some respondents picked "other" and cited "mall" which was a public health clinic). I could easily do this by hand but want to learn the code to select "mall" strings then use logical expressions to assign these people to "public health clinic" (e.g. create a new variable for location of flu clinics).

My categorical variable is "lrecflu2" and my character string variable is "lfother"

So far I have:

```
mall <- grep("MALL", Motiv82012$lfother, value = TRUE)
```

This gives me a vector with all the string responses containing "MALL" (all strings are in caps in the dataframe)

How do I use this vector in a logical expression to create a new variable that assigns these people to the "public health clinic" category and assigns the original value of flu clinic location variable for people that did not select "other" (and do not have values in the character string variable) to the new flu clinic location variable?

Perhaps, grep is not even the right function to be using.

Comment: I don't get it - but perhabs you are looking for `grepl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you have a column in a data frame, where you want to reassign one character value to another. If so, you were almost there...

```
set.seed(1) # for generating an example
df1 <- data.frame(flu2=sample(c("MALL","other","PHC"),size=10,replace=TRUE))
df1$flu2[grep("MALL",df1$flu2)] <- "PHC"
```

Here `grep()` is giving you the required vector index; you then subset the vector based on this and change those elements.

**Update 2**

This should produce a `data.frame` similar to the one you are using:

```
set.seed(1)
lreflu2 <- sample(c("PHC","Med","Work","other"),size=10,replace=TRUE)
Ifother <- rep("",10) # blank character vector
s1 <- c("Frontenac Mall","Kingston Mall","notMALL")
Ifother[lreflu2=="other"] <- s1
df1 <- data.frame(lreflu2,Ifother)
### alternative:
### df1 <- data.frame(lreflu2,Ifother, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1
```

gives:

```
   lreflu2        Ifother
1      Med               
2      Med               
3     Work               
4    other Frontenac Mall
5      PHC               
6    other  Kingston Mall
7    other        notMALL
8     Work               
9     Work               
10     PHC
```

If you're looking for an exact string match you don't need `grep` at all:

```
df1$lreflu2[df1$Ifother=="MALL"] <- "PHC"
```

Using a `regex`:

```
df1$lreflu2[grep("Mall",df1$Ifother)] <- "PHC"
```

gives:

```
   lreflu2        Ifother
1      Med               
2      Med               
3     Work               
4      PHC Frontenac Mall
5      PHC               
6      PHC  Kingston Mall
7    other        notMALL
8     Work               
9     Work               
10     PHC
```

Whether `Ifother` is a factor or vector with mode character doesn't affect things. `data.frame` will coerce string vectors to factors by default.

Comment: I think this could work but it's actually two variables, your example appears to be only the one => 1) lrecflu2 has the categories "PHC", "Med clinic/office", "Work", "Other." All are mutually exclusive. If respondents pick "Other" they are then asked to elaborate - this elaboration is a string var called lfother. Since some who pick "Other" give the "mall" as a location, I want to assign them to "PHC" in the lrecflu2 variable (although not overwrite the original) because this is actually a "PHC"

Comment: Will this work if Ifother has more than one word? E.g if someone says Frontenac Mall or Kingston Mall? Will it still pick "Mall" out? Ifother is not a factor variable

Comment: Pleasure. May I suggest shortening the names of your variables in future, in order to make the examples easier to write?